# Highslide popup in Highcharts not showing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, highslide

When you click on a datapoint in this example, the popup appears but it is all the way in the corner, and it is not sized properly. Can anyone see any immediate problems?

The live code is here http://goo.gl/q8sfH

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>
<!-- Additional files for the Highslide popup effect -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.highcharts.com/highslide/highslide-full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.highcharts.com/highslide/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.highcharts.com/highslide/highslide.css" />


        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'scatter',
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Companies'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'data.com proprietary professional'
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    enabled: true,
                    text: 'Future Outlook'
                },
                startOnTick: true,
                endOnTick: true,
                showLastLabel: true
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Current Quarter'
                },
                    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return this.value + ' ';
        }
    },

            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: 100,
                y: 70,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                borderWidth: 1
            },
            plotOptions: {
                scatter: {
                    marker: {
                        radius: 5,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true,
                                lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            marker: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                        pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
                    },



                cursor: 'pointer',
                events: {
                            click: function() {
                                hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                                    pageOrigin: {
                                        x: this.pageX,
                                        y: this.pageY
                                    },
  //                                  headingText: this.series.name,
                                    maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) +':<br/> '+
                                        this.y +' visits',
                                    width: 200
                                });
                            }
                }



                }
            },



                    series: [{
                    name: 'Nasdaq',
                    color: 'red',
            data: [
            { y: 1,x:4,ticker:'KORS'}, {y: 5,x:2,ticker:'LULU'}, {x:0,y:0,ticker:'ZNGA'}, {x:.4,y:1,ticker:'JCP'}, {x:.6,y:2.5,ticker:'DECK'}

            ]},{name:'SP',color:'green',data:[
        {x:6,y:6,ticker:'lulu'},{x:10,y:10,ticker:'GPS'},{x:7,y:6.6,ticker:'FB'}
        ]},{name:'Inline Company Performance',color:'darkgrey',data:[

        {x:5,y:5,ticker:'GIII'},{x:5.3,y:4.3,ticker:'BNNY'}

        ]}]





        });
    });


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="../../js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

this.pageX and this.pageY are undefined as you have them now.

Replace this:

```
click: function() {
    hs.htmlExpand(null, {
        pageOrigin: {
            x: this.pageX,
            y: this.pageY
        },
        headingText: this.name,
        maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) +':<br/> '+
        this.y +' visits',
        width: 200
    });
}
```

with this:

```
click: function(e) {
    hs.htmlExpand(null, {
        pageOrigin: {
            x: e.pageX,
            y: e.pageY
        },
        headingText: this.name,
        maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) +':<br/> '+
        this.y +' visits',
        width: 200
    });
}
```

invoke 'e' in the function(), and the reference it for the pageX and pageY

---

Edit to clarify and to answer your secondary question:

if you put the event inside the point object instead, you can skip the above change, and you can then use your this.x and this.y to pull in your other data elements from the point that was clicked on:

```
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                        click: function() {
                            hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                                pageOrigin: {
                                    x: this.pageX,
                                    y: this.pageY
                                },
                                headingText: this.series.name,
                                maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) +':<br/> '+
                                    this.y +' visits',
                                width: 200
                            });
                        }
                }
            }
```

Although the x value that you are trying to format as a date is not a date, so you will get a 12/31/1969 from that probably...

Comment: How were you able to see that? I did not catch that when I was investigating the chrome console. but you were right, changing that made it work. If it is not too much, how would one be able to get the 'ticker' category, or another part of the data into that popup? the current "this.y" and "this.x" does not work, and changing it to "e.y" does not either.

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.category` if you need values of **X-axis**